# CSS font-smoothing: antialiasied não faz diferença?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

É possível no falecido Fireworks cs6 (e pelo o que li no photoshop também) otimizar a renderização das fontes. Pesquisando para ver era possível aplicar isto nas páginas web vi que há sim recursos para realizar o mesmo:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

Entretanto testando não vi diferença alguma! E pelo o que pesquisei nos sites, mesmo nos exemplos não vi diferença alguma.
O que gostaria de saber é se isto já está implementado nos navegadores por padrão? Ou ainda se realmente há diferença na renderização da fonte quando é utilizado estas propriedades CSS? Ou se não, se realmente font-smoothing é uma propriedade que carrega mais código CSS.
Se quiserem indicar sites que esclareçam mais esta questão também.

*OBS: Não estou falando de renderização de imagem, mas sim de fonte de texto mesmo. Obrigado*

Comment: Aí você não está otimizando, está estragando. Renderização em subpixel é melhor que antialias em qualquer monitor LCD. Antialias era pra monitor de tubo. Essa gambiarra aí era pra disfarçar o render ruim de um certo browser famoso, depois deram uma consertada no browser, e não precisa mais disso. O firefox tinha uma coisa parecida especificamente para Mac, mas removeram.

Comment: Tou sem tempo pra elaborar uma resposta completa, mas achei uma referência razoável aqui (en) que explica o essencial: http://usabilitypost.com/2012/11/05/stop-fixing-font-smoothing/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Renderização em subpixel gera um melhor resultado em monitores atuais, antigamente era utilizado devido a tecnologia dos monitores mais antigos.

Sugiro dar uma lida neste [artigo](http://usabilitypost.com/2012/11/05/stop-fixing-font-smoothing/) que explica bem as diferenças e o por que não utilizar mais o antialised.